# Close angular CDK overlay by click button

Tags: angular, overlay

I'm creating service for modal window with angular cdk overlay and I have followed this tutorial : [Tutorial](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html)

I would like to somehow pass reference of this overlay to overlayed component because I would like to close this component by clicking on button. Can anybody help me how to pass or extract reference?

I have tried to import FilePreviewOverlayRef in to file-preview-overlay.component but it did not help.

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-overlay-step-4-xvk5ih)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-overlay-step-4-jdzlce), I modified your code a bit. That's not an optimal solution but you will have an idea at least.

[ComponentPortal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api) has a property called injector that is used for the instantiation of the component. I used that to inject initial data (in your case it is FilePreviewOverlayService) to overlay.

Comment: I'm also facing this type of a situation, instead of click I want to create a popover "mouseenter". 

I created a custom directive for showing this, and I'm listening to "mouseenter" to create an overlay. 

The issue is when I move form one element to other I need to remove the old one. We can't simply detach() on "mouseleave" because the popover should be closed only while clicking outside. 

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple implementation:

```
<button (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" type="button" cdkOverlayOrigin 
    #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
    {{isOpen ? "Close" : "Open"}}
</button>
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen" 
    [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true"
    (backdropClick)="isOpen = false">
</ng-template>
```

the **backdropClick** event close the Overlay.

Comment: thanks for the awesome code. but is there a way without backdrop and click outside we can hide it.

Comment: If you add a "random class name" the backdrop won't be dark.
I.e. `cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass="no-style-class-to-hide-backdrop"`